# How can i display the 4th element of an array as the content of an info window?

Tags: javascript, arrays, infowindow, markers

Hi everyone I am creating an info window for each of my markers and then I pass the content to a variable in order to assigne the 4th element of the array as the content but it seems that it is not working. Any idea of how I could display the 4th element of the array in to each of the info window? Many thanks.

```
var infowindow = null;
function initialize() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.474, -1.868);

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
var image = 'marker1.png';

var countries = [
['england', 51.508515 , -0.125487, 5,'this is england'],
['france', 46.227638 , 2.213749, 4,'this is france'],
['switcherland', 46.818188 , 8.227512, 3,'this is switcherland'],
['italy', 41.871940 , 12.56738, 2,'this is italy'],
['greece', 39.074208 , 21.824312, 1,'this is greece']
];


 setMarkers(map, countries);
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({

    content: 'hi'
        });


function setMarkers(map, markers) {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var countries = markers[i];
        var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(countries[1], countries[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: siteLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: countries[0],
            zIndex: countries[6],
            html: countries[6]

        });



        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {


            infowindow.open(map,this);
        });
    }
 }
 }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: The problem is fixed by setting 
     ` html: countries[4] `
from
     ` html:countries[6]`

That way it gets the 5th index of the array for each marker.

Answer (score 1):

```
var countries
```

is an array of arrays. The **index 4** actually points to the **5th element** of the array (array indexes start at 0) so with

```
var contentString = countries[4]
```

you are getting the **array**, not a string!

```
['greece', 39.074208 , 21.824312, 1,'this is greece']
```

It looks as though you want the 5th element of this array (index 4)

```
contentString[4]
```

would be **'this is greece'**

Comment: as you can see on my code I am getting the 4th index of the array.    `var contentString = countries[4];`
 the problem is why its not getting recognised ;/

Comment: Yes, as outlined in my answer this is going to be an array, not a string. Do you want the 4th index of contentString?